# Create a lightning bolt design (like The Flash)

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

[image: T-shirt with Flash symbol]

I am trying to re-create the lightning bolt symbol from The Flash (DC Comics) (or the T-shirt worn by *Big Bang Theory*'s Sheldon Cooper) in CSS.

This is going to act like a star rating system, only a 'lightning rating system' instead.

However, since I'm trying to keep the HTML to a minimum, I'd like to style this in CSS only.

I have got to the stage of:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(79, 79, 79, 1) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 100%);
}
.wrap {
  height: 50vw;
  width: 50vw;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.circ:hover{
  background:gray;
  }
.circ:hover .bolt{
  background:gold;
  }
.circ {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow:0 0 10px 2px black;
}
.bolt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 70%;
  width: 30%;
  background: yellow;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
  transform: perspective(200px) skewX(-10deg) rotateX(15deg);
}
.bolt:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 20%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transform:  ;
}
/*
.bolt:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:-40%;left:20%;
  height:50%;
  width:100%;
  background:inherit;
  transform:perspective(50px) skewX(-10deg) rotateX(45deg);
  }*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="circ">

    <div class="bolt"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but do not know how to continue from here.

I've attempted using the `perspective` property, although I don't think I've quite got a handle on it as of yet - mainly because I'm slightly confused as to what it is doing to the `:before` and `:after` properties when it is applied to the parent.

I have chosen CSS for this as the white background and bolt colour will be changing on click, and because I know how to do that with CSS.

(I know SVG may be a better option here, but I have not been able to learn this due to time restrictions, so I'd prefer to use 'what I know how to use', which is, CSS)

Comment: "Big Bang Theory"...heh...It's the [**Flash's logo**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=the+flash&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=955&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=ZiBwVfr6M4HaUr-vgXg&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#tbm=isch&q=the+flash+symbol)

Comment: @Paulie_D: Sorry was typing big bang lol... It's bad when you relate a logo more to a TV show than the original comic itself! :S

Comment: I have to say though that this is a **shipload** of mark-up for something that **should** be the province of an image. I think you are working too hard for something that isn't really necessary.

Comment: @Paulie_D: You should know me by now that I don't do anything the easy way (mainly because I'm an idiot, partly because I know I am an idiot).

Comment: What's to learn?  If you can figure out how to use the pen tool in Illustrator, you can have your SVG in less than 2 minutes.  If Illustrator is out of your price range, Inkscape is free.

Comment: @cimmanon: I might just have to look into Inkscape, (cheers for the info). But I've yet been able to learn (even through multiple analysis of other's answers) how to animate/manipulate the svg. I've always found css' manipulation easier to work with. But one day I hope to really jump into learning svg, I just haven't the time to learn it all now, that all.

Comment: Even if somehow an image would be much more appropriate (semantically) to achieve the same visual result, I must say I'm really impressed with the various solutions...

Comment: This reminds me of the time I came up with a way to create arbitrary 80x15 buttons with CSS, then compared the bytes of the markup to the size of the equivalent png (and the DOM complexity) and understood why images are the way to go with this stuff. Honestly, I find doing things with CSS and markup rather than images to be tons more interesting and fun, but unless you're taking advantage of the markup version (for animations, dynamic changes etc.) images, while mundane, are the way to go. If you just want a picture, use an image - not for the semantics, but for size and simplicity.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but why not just use images instead of generating an image via CSS?

Comment: @Omegacron: http://robertnyman.com/2010/04/21/using-css-instead-of-images-when-coding-your-web-design/

Comment: I find it interesting that for you css is easier to work with in this case. If you want a circle in svg, you write "circle". If you want a circle in css... well, look at your `.circ`. Are you sure this is easier to work with?

Comment: I don't see how this question can be described as having "too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format". The answers are all pretty straightforward and simple, I vote for re-open :)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

## SVG

Here you go <strike>@Professor.CSS</strike>. @jbutler483
[A Circle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle)
[And Polygon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon)

```css
svg {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 150">
  <circle fill="white" stroke="black" cx="50" cy="75" r="50"></circle>
  <polygon stroke="gray" fill="yellow" points="100,0 67,50 90,45 47,100 70,95 0,150 27,110 12,113 50,70 30,73 100,0" />
</svg>
```

### or css

Its just `::before` and `::after` elements on the lighting. 
`drop-shadow` on the lighting container.

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}
.container {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 0px gray);
}
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-color: black;
}
.lightning {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: skewX(-30deg) skewY(-30deg) rotate(10deg);
  background-color: yellow;
}
.lightning:before {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 40px 30px;
  border-color: transparent transparent yellow transparent;
  top: -39px;
  left: -17px;
  content: "";
}
.lightning:after {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 40px 30px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent yellow;
  bottom: -39px;
  right: -17px;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="lightning"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @tommydevs I don't know CSS well. I know how to use the little i know in a creative way.

Comment: I was going to suggest that SVG is probably smaller than CSS for this. +1

Comment: The second solution is horribly off on some browsers, like my tablet's Chrome.

Comment: In terms of semantics, compatibility, and robustness, the first solution is good and the second is bad.

Answer (score 50):

> Disclaimer: Use SVG for complex images. We can still have some fun with CSS, though, just use this for learning and not production implementation.

## Is this possible with a single HTML element?

### Yeah! ... with limitations — mainly no border on the bolt... but, hey, minimal HTML!

- The top and bottom sections are created with the [transparent border triangle trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7073484/2930477) on `:before` and `:after`
- The middle bolt is created with the `box-shadow` of `:before`

#### Very rough example

**Note:** This example uses a `<div>`, as it requires pseudo-element children.

```css
body {
  background: #F00;
}
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 5px #000;
  margin-top: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(20deg);
}
div:before {
  border-right: solid 70px yellow;
  border-top: solid 160px transparent;
  box-shadow: 50px 100px yellow;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  top: -70px;
}
div:after {
  border-right: solid 70px transparent;
  border-top: solid 160px yellow;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Only 1 html, that's automatic win :)

Comment: @Paul *element, not 1 html,

Comment: You've chosen the wrong HTML element. The correct element is `<img>`.

Comment: @zzzzBov  sure, but this technique requires pseudo-element children, which `<img>` can't have.

Comment: @zzzzBov Have you marked my answer as not useful? If it helps, I have added a disclaimer that SVG should be used (which it should) and clarified the use of `<div>`. Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 41):

> Disclaimer: I recommend SVG for these but that doesn't mean we shouldn't be having fun with CSS. Use this for learning but not production implementation.

Here is a method to achieve the shape with just a single element (+ a couple of pseudos) and some background `linear-gradients`. The shape can be scaled without any distortions.

**Explanation on how the shape was achieved:**

- The white circle with the black border is a normal CSS circle created using `border-radius` on a pseudo-element (`:after`).
- Another pseudo-element (`:before`) is added and is skewed along both X and Y axes to give the bolt's parts a skewed appearance.
- The bolt is actually created by stacking multiple `linear-gradients` on top of one another. It involves 6 gradient images where 3 are for the inside yellow part of the bolt and the other 3 are for the gray borders.
- The size of the background images (gradients) are determined by the size of the bolt and each of them is positioned in such a way that they produce the lightning bolt like appearance.
- The center part of the bolt actually has only one solid color but is still produced using a gradient because we can't control the size of solid color backgrounds.

<sup>Note: Scaling works pretty well if `transform: scale(...)` is used instead of a height/width change + transition.</sup>

```css
.lightning {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.lightning:after,
.lightning:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
}
.lightning:after {
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.lightning:before {
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 0%, yellow 0%), linear-gradient(to top left, yellow 43%, gray 43%, gray 44%, transparent 44%), linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 56%, gray 56%, gray 57%, yellow 57%), linear-gradient(transparent 0%, gray 0%), linear-gradient(to top left, gray 51%, transparent 51%), linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 49%, gray 49%);
  background-size: 20% 40%, 22% 42%, 22% 42%, 23% 42%, 23% 42%, 23% 42%;
  background-position: 50% 50%, 32% 5%, 70% 100%, 50% 50%, 33% 7%, 69% 98%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: skewY(-30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

/* Just for demo */

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
.lightning {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.lightning:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<!-- Script used only for avoidance of prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<div class="lightning"></div>
```

---

**With Animation for Bolt:**

```css
.lightning {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.lightning:after, .lightning:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
}
.lightning:after {
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.lightning:before {
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 0%, yellow 0%), linear-gradient(to top left, yellow 43%, gray 43%, gray 44%, transparent 44%), linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 56%, gray 56%, gray 57%, yellow 57%), linear-gradient(transparent 0%, gray 0%), linear-gradient(to top left, gray 51%, transparent 51%), linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 49%, gray 49%);
  background-size: 20% 40%, 22% 42%, 22% 42%, 23% 42%, 23% 42%, 23% 42%;
  background-position: 50% 50%, 32% 5%, 70% 100%, 50% 50%, 33% 7%, 69% 98%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: skewY(-30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

/* Just for demo */

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
.lightning {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.lightning:hover:before {
  animation: boltstrike 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes boltstrike {
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-5%) translateY(5%) skewY(-30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(7.5%) translateY(-7.5%) skewY(-30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: skewY(-30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  }
}
@keyframes boltstrike {
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-5%) translateY(5%) skewY(-30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(5%) translateY(-5%) skewY(-30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: skewY(-30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<div class="lightning"></div>
```

[**Click here**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/LVWXoM/) for a full demo with animation, color change on click etc.

---

**Older version without border:**

```css
.lightning {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.lightning:after,
.lightning:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
}
.lightning:after {
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.lightning:before {
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 0%, yellow 0%), linear-gradient(to top left, yellow 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 50%, yellow 50%);
  background-size: 20% 40%, 20% 40%, 20% 40%;
  background-position: 50% 50%, 30% 5%, 70% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: skewY(-30deg) skewX(-30deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

/* Just for demo */

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
.lightning {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.lightning:hover {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Script used only for avoidance of prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<div class="lightning"></div>
```

---

Comment: very smart tweaking of background properties!

Comment: Nice disclaimer Harry

Answer (score 16):

Managed to complete this using CSS skews and rotates with some positioning.

Its not the cleanest and its also not great for responsiveness or changing the size but it works and its as close as I could get with my short space of time.

Code is below:

```css
#lightning {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 600px;
  background: red;
}
.above,
.below {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}
.above .middle {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 125px;
  width: 400px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(111deg) skew(35deg);
  transform: rotate(111deg) skew(35deg);
}
.above .toptri {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  top: -175px;
  left: 300px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) skew(141deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg) skew(141deg);
  border-top: 0px transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 128px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 284px solid #FFFF00;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(350deg) skew(141deg);
  transform: rotate(350deg) skew(141deg);
}
.above .bottri {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 400px;
  left: 125px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) skew(141deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg) skew(141deg);
  border-top: 0px transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 128px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 284px solid #FFFF00;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(170deg) skew(141deg);
  transform: rotate(170deg) skew(141deg);
}
.below .middle {
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 280px;
  left: 80px;
  height: 165px;
  width: 440px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(111deg) skew(35deg);
  transform: rotate(111deg) skew(35deg);
}
.below .toptri {
  position: absolute;
  height: 160px;
  width: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  top: -200px;
  left: 265px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) skew(141deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg) skew(141deg);
  border-top: 0px transparent;
  border-left: 80px solid transparent;
  border-right: 158px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 370px solid grey;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(350deg) skew(141deg);
  transform: rotate(350deg) skew(141deg);
}
.below .bottri {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 400px;
  left: 125px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) skew(141deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg) skew(141deg);
  border-top: 0px transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 128px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 284px solid #FFFF00;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(170deg) skew(141deg);
  transform: rotate(170deg) skew(141deg);
}
.below .bottri {
  position: absolute;
  height: 160px;
  width: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 380px;
  left: 100px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) skew(141deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg) skew(141deg);
  border-top: 0px transparent;
  border-left: 80px solid transparent;
  border-right: 158px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 370px solid grey;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(170deg) skew(141deg);
  transform: rotate(170deg) skew(141deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="lightning">
  <div class="below">
    <div class="toptri"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="bottri"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="above">
    <div class="toptri"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="bottri"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/stewartside/pen/ZGeMqm)

Answer (score 13):

**CSS**

CSS only using `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements, CSS triangles and `transform`. It would be difficult to make this particular solution responsive given the usage of CSS triangles as `border`s cannot be percentage based. This solution uses two `div`s as the basis of the lightning bolt and it's outline.

The bolt is created in the following way:

- The middle of the bolt is specified in `.boltOuter`/`.boltInner`. It is a rectangle skewed on the X and Y axis to make it a tilted rhombus
- The "prongs" are the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements positioned relatively to the container `.boltOuter`/`.boltInner`
- The "prongs" are made using CSS triangles (zero `height` and `width` elements with selective `border`s). The triangles are rotated to get the desired angle
- All elements of `.boltInner` are made smaller and offset from `.boltOuter` to allow `.boltOuter`  to act as the silver outline

```css
body {
    background-color: red;
}
.circle {
    background-color: white;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    left: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    width: 400px;
}
.boltOuter, .boltInner {
    position: absolute;
}
.boltOuter:before, .boltOuter:after, .boltInner:before, .boltInner:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotateY(-60deg);
    width: 0;
}
.boltOuter {
    background-color: silver;
    height: 300px;
    left: 140px;
    top: 50px;
    transform: skewX(-10deg) skewY(-20deg);
    width: 110px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.boltOuter:before, .boltOuter:after {
    border: 150px solid transparent;
    z-index: 1;
}
.boltOuter:before {
    border-bottom-color: silver;
    border-right-color: silver;
    left: -150px;
    top: -200px;
}
.boltOuter:after {
    border-left-color: silver;
    border-top-color: silver;
    bottom: -200px;
    right: -150px;
}
.boltInner {
    background-color: gold;
    height: 290px;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 4;
}
.boltInner:before, .boltInner:after {
    border: 140px solid transparent;
    z-index: 3;
}
.boltInner:before {
    border-bottom-color: gold;
    border-right-color: gold;
    left: -143px;
    top: -190px;
}
.boltInner:after {
    border-top-color: gold;
    border-left-color: gold;
    bottom: -190px;
    right: -143px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
    <div class="boltOuter">
        <div class="boltInner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/o7gm6dsb/

Comment: This solution is really good. And you thoroughly explain how you did it. +1

Comment: Have to say that I still like this answer of yours more than the other :)

Comment: @Harry Yeah, the other one was a little left field :). Love the animation you added to your answers by the way!

Answer (score 11):

**A different CSS method which can obtain the result with a single `div`.**

This method uses an custom icon font generated by using http://fontello.com/, the benefit of this being that a font is scalable with little effort or code required.

- The font is included using `@font-face`. In this example the font is directly embedded into the CSS file
- `.bolt` is used to draw out the containing circle by using `border-radius: 50%;`
- The `:before` pseudo element is used for the bolt, positioned relatively to `.bolt` and centered to allow it to go outside the circle borders
- In newer webkit browsers `-webkit-text-stroke: 3px silver;` can be used to provide an outline to the bolt
- If `-webkit-text-stroke` is not supported `text-shadow` can be used to provide a makeshift border instead

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontello';
  src: url('data:application/octet-stream;base64,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') format('woff'),
url('data:application/octet-stream;base64,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') format('truetype');
}
body {
  background-color: red;
}
.bolt {
  background-color: white;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}
.bolt:before {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 3px silver;
  color: gold;
  content: '\e800';
  display: block;
  font-family: "fontello";
  font-size: 200px;
  line-height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 2px 0 0 silver, -2px 0 0 silver, 0 2px 0 silver, 0 -2px 0 silver, 1px 1px silver, -1px -1px 0 silver, 1px -1px 0 silver, -1px 1px 0 silver;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bolt"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve a slightly different lighting bolt with [html symbols](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp). Note that not all browsers support all of them.

Here is a quick example what you can do with just css/html.

```css
.circle {
 border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid black;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
    font-size: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: white;
}

.square{
    border: 4px solid red;
    width: 106px;
    height: 106px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
    <div class="circle">⚡</div>
</div>
```

Advantage of this one is that this is simple, does not require anything. Disadvantage is that the bolt is slightly different and that not all browsers might support the symbol.

If you need exact picture, generate it in SVG and add as an svg or a font.

Sadly enough it looks like the sign is not visible on windows, but on macos (chrome) it looks this way:

[image]

On ubuntu it also visible, but looks differently.

Comment: Just shows a box in my browser (Version 43.0.2357.81 m). How do I get it to show the actual character?

Comment: @user13267 what is your browser and OS? You posted just a version.

Comment: Sorry Browser is Chrome Version 43.0.2357.81 m and OS is Windows 7 32 bit

Comment: @user13267 this is sad :-(. I just checked and it really does not work on windows (I added example in macos, and it also works on ubuntu).

Comment: On linux (fedora) here Chrome 42. The icon hows, but it all black. :) I like the simplicity of this answer.

Comment: @Persijn there are a lot of different symbols there. You can create the whole chessboard just in CSS.

Answer (score 2):

I know you don't want SVG, but it's really easy, and way faster than making it with css:

- Make a screenshot of your lightning bolt.
- Go to: http://www.base64-image.de/ upload the image(jpg, png, gif).
- Get the css background image code

Comment: This is a good option but the way it's written makes it sound like this gives you an SVG scalable vector graphic. It doesn't, it gives you a PNG-24 pixel (raster) graphic in base 64 encoding. (this also means it has better browser support than SVG - base-64 PNGs work in IE8 and old android browsers, whereas SVG doesn't)

Comment: I guess the OP knew he can use images, were it base64 encoded or simply plain old files on the server...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use magical **[Drawsvg](http://www.drawsvg.org/)** Web Site that allow you to release your imagination and draw freely your SVG objects without any prerequisites or skills.

[image]

When you finish drawing you have just to click on save button and you get your SVG code, The code for the example in the previous image :

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" >
    <rect id="svgEditorBackground" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="200" style="stroke: none;" fill="red"/>
    <circle id="e1_circle" cx="50.9398" cy="93.985" stroke="black" style="stroke-width: 1px; vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;" r="48.5487" fill="white" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -1.12782 4.13534)"/><g id="e4_group" fill="yellow" style=""/>
    <polyline stroke="black" id="e5_polyline" style="stroke-width: 1px; vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;" points="67.1053 21.8045 33.6466 74.812 50.188 69.5489 25 114.286 45.6767 106.767 14.8496 158.271 70.8647 92.8571 45.3008 97.7444 69.3609 56.391 50.188 62.0301 66.7293 21.8045" fill="yellow"/>
</svg>
```

Hope this helps.